# dask.dataframe.read_csv can't access file on network server

Tags: python, dask

This might look like a duplicate but I haven't been able to solve my issue using other questions. I've reached a dark and lonely cul-de-sac trying to read a very large csv file located on a network server (not mapped) using dask.data.frame.read_csv. I've checked all git issues and even the dask documentation (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html) and tried all possible combinations of '\', '\', '/', and '//' in the file path but to no avail.

First i ensured that the os path to the file exists. and it does! but dask cannot access the file, which cannot be copied to my own local drive (for data privacy reasons, and also the large size of the data)

Local OS is (forcibly) Windows (puke). Python 3.7

The file path in Windows (explorer) is something like this:

```
\\server_name\some_path\some_more_path\the_file.csv
```

when I check the os path to the file, it exists:

```
import os
os.path.exists("\\\\server_name\\some_path\\some_more_path\\the_file.csv")

    Out[74]: True
```

But then I've tried all sorts of file paths to read the file using dask and I receive either a file path error or syntax error.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
# failed --> changes the path to local drive 
my_file = dd.read_csv("\\\\server_name\\some_path\\some_more_path\\the_file.csv")




  File "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 56, in info
    out = os.stat(path, follow_symlinks=False)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/my_user/server_name/some_path/some_more_path/the_file.csv'

################################
    # failed, same error as above
    my_file = dd.read_csv('file://server_name/some_path/some_more_path/the_file.csv')

    File "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 56, in info
            out = os.stat(path, follow_symlinks=False)

        FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/my_user/server_name/some_path/some_more_path/the_file.csv'



################################   
    # failed --> label syntax error
    my_file = dd.read_csv("file:\\\\server_name\\some_path\\some_more_path\\the_file.csv")

    File "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 56, in info
                    out = os.stat(path, follow_symlinks=False)

    OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'file:\\\\server_name\\some_path\\clive_folder\\some_more_path\\test.csv'
```

these are only a few out of the nearly 15 combinations I've tried. I'm starting to think that maybe it's not possible to read a file from network using dask?

Comment: What is your version of fsspec?

Comment: version fsspec  0.5.2

Comment: after upgrading fsspec to 0.6.2. removing the 'file:' from string worked!!! Thank you so much. So, this works now my_file = dd.read_csv("\\\\server_name\\some_path\\some_more_path\\the_file.csv")